# Gluon Scene Builder Freezes

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I'm configuring the style of my form that I want to change its background color, in the *JavaFX CSS section* there was **2** textfield; one for the tag(eg. -fx-border-color) and the other is the value in it. Everytime after I inputted the first textfield I began to switch to the value textfield but the scene builder suddenly freezes. I checked it on my task manager but I found it that it doesn't consume cpu and its instance is still there. What could be the problem?

Comment: What is your Scene Builder version, and your OS? Can you post your FXML and CSS files (or at least something that can reproduce your issue...)?

Comment: If you can reliably reproduce the problem, and your using the latest version of Scene Builder, please [submit an issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/issues) if one doesn't already exist. Describe the _exact_ steps necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of the Scene Builder freezing when adding a `Tab` element to a `TabPane` etc, and first Running the `SceneBuilder` application ***as an Administrator*** and manually opening the the `.fxml` file from the Scene Builder has solved this issue. This might not be a permanent fix, but it will be a temporary workaround.